# VBA code to find, based on two criteria, and replace a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginning of VBA codes so still very much learning, i have a code which searches for the value in one cell, then updates another value from another cell.
However i now need it to search depending on two criterias, if they match then i would like another cell to be updated with an inputted value.
The code i have for one find is

```vb
For Each ssh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ssh.Name <> "Input" And ssh.Name <> "Calendar" And _
    ssh.Name <> "List" And ssh.Name <> "2020" Then
    ssh.Visible = True
    ssh.UnProtect
    Set fn = ssh.Range("B:B").Find(sh.Range("C20").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    
        If Not fn Is Nothing Then
            adr = fn.Address
            Do
                 ssh.Range("C" & fn.Row) = sh.Range("E20").Value
                 Set fn = ssh.Range("B:B").FindNext(fn)
            Loop While adr <> fn.Address
        End If
    If fn Is Nothing Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
    ssh.Visible = False
    ssh.Protect
    End If
```

But i dont know how to modify this?
The criteria values will be in cells C20 and D20 and columns B and A respectively on the searched sheets, if they match then i need the corresponding row in column C to be updated with the value in E20

I hope this is enough information and makes sense... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Really just need an `If` added inside your loop to check for the second criteria

```vb
Dim skipSheets, ssh As Worksheet

skipSheets = Array("Input", "Calendar", "List", "2020")

For Each ssh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(ssh.Name, skipSheets, 0)) Then
        ssh.Visible = True
        ssh.Unprotect
        Set fn = ssh.Range("B:B").Find(sh.Range("C20").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        
        If Not fn Is Nothing Then
            adr = fn.Address
            Do
                If fn.Offset(0, -1).Value = sh.Range("D20").Value Then
                    fn.Offset(0, 1).Value = sh.Range("E20").Value
                End If
                Set fn = ssh.Range("B:B").FindNext(fn)
            Loop While adr <> fn.Address
        End If
        
        If fn Is Nothing Then cnt = cnt + 1
        
        ssh.Visible = False
        ssh.Protect
    End If
Next ssh
```

Comment: Thanks - sorry but what does  fn.Offset(0, -1) mean?

Comment: Hi i have tried this code however now i get a 'compile error: Next without For' error?

Comment: `fn` is a cell and `fn.Offset(0, -1)` is the cell to the left of that (-1 columns)